How do we express the idea that we look at the lesson that our teacher is going to teach so that we won't be so puzzled?
We say "I reviewed the lesson", it means I have already learned the lesson and now I looked at it again for reinforcement/memorization right?

review [transitive, intransitive] (especially North American English)
to look again at something you have studied, especially in order to
prepare for an exam
review something We will be reviewing all the topics covered this
semester.

That is North American English, I am not sure if people also say "review" in British English.
Now, my daughter's teacher asks her to look at the lesson that she is going to teach the next day so that she won't feel too unfamiliar or puzzled or bewildered (not sure which word is right)?
Do we have a word for it?
For example, "she has to pre-read the lesson" or "she has to take a "look at the lesson ahead of time." or "she previewed the lesson" something like that.

We can review a lesson without having understood any of it! Like me with algebra aged 13. It means the same in British English.

The teacher asked her to preview tomorrow's lesson content at home.

In AmE, review can also mean "look something over for (what is for you) the first time".  The re prefix is not wrong inasmuch as the person who produced the thing has already gone over it before.  You're the second set of eyes. Or maybe the 100th.    See M-W review v. #4.

Review is also used for studying something especially before an exam or test.
Merriam-Webster

Review
2: revision sense 1a
7b(1): renewed study of material previously studied


Read
transitive verb
1 d (1): to become acquainted with or look over the contents of (something, such as a book)

If you read something "in advance" it means you are reading ahead of time, you can also state when this reading should be done by.

You should "read Unit 2 in advance".
Read chapter 2 for class tomorrow

The teacher might add: check the meanings of words you don't understand, underline the most important words in the text etc.

"Review" and "preview" are words more suitable for adults studying something thoroughly.
For a child, use a suitable phrase which means to take a casual look. For example:
"Take a glimpse" at tomorrow's lesson.
OR.
"Take a glance" at what you are going to study.

Yes. In my day it was called 'reading over' the next day's lesson.
